# How to redirect user from OWIN middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, owin-middleware

I have middleware used for authentication purposes and need to distinguish users by the type if they are internal or external. After this I want to redirect external users to custom error page, because they should not have access to particular section of my site.

I wanted to throw `HttpResponseException` with my custom status code and handle it by linking in web config's section `customErrors` with my error page. However I cannot use custom status code this way and to use one of the existing codes is bad idea in my case.

To be honest I am quite new to OWIN middleware and I am not even sure what to google. I will be most grateful for hints how to solve such situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey take a look at this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureApp(app);
            //Some other code here
            if (_helper.IsNew())
            {
                Debug.Write("This is a new guy. Redirect him to the setup page permanently");

                var ctx = new OwinContext();
                ctx.Response.Redirect("/Setup");//This is how I redirect from Startip.cs

            }            

        }
```

Observe the code where I am checking in IF for truthy, on true I will create a new OWIN CONTEXT and do redirect there.
I can also specify the redirection status code: 301/302. But without that also the above code works just fine

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set `response code` (`303 See Other`) to the `response` object in middle-ware and a `location` header to where you want to redirect user.

When you do that based you you business logic you should not call `next` function and user will be redirected to new location (if no other middle-ware down the stack will change the response).

Remember to register your middle-ware before web api or mvc.

You can google for `web api building custom middleware`. Here is an example article you could find [Writing Custom Middleware for ASP.NET](https://shellmonger.com/2015/07/20/writing-custom-middleware-for-asp-net/).